# How can I stop double-sided printing from breaking?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

We have a customer that generates reports using our software platform that utilizes Crystal Reports. Every now and then changes to the report are requested. All employees have virtual machines that have Crystal Reports and other software installed to make changes to customer items such as this one report template.

Every time we make modifications to the crystal report template and save it, even if it's something as insignificant as moving a text field up by 1 inch, double-sided printing breaks; instead of flipping text on the long edge of the page, two 1-sided pages are printed. However, that there is exactly **one employee VM** that does **NOT** break double-sided printing when the rpt is modified.

I have never seen anything like this. We have checked just about everything and don't know where to go next:

- Customer printer settings are confirmed set to double-sided printing
- Crystal Reports settings are identical
- Section formulas and settings are identical
- Making a 1:1 copy of the one working VM and making changes on the copy still breaks printing.

The only remaining suspicion I have left is the file format schema. We have access to Crystal Reports 11 Release 2 (11.5), but the schema is version 11.0.0. Can altering an 11.0.0 report using 11.5 cause this issue? Are there any other areas we should check that could be breaking printing?

[image: Report rpt details]

[image: Current CR version]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out our installation files for Crystal Reports XI R2 were corrupt somehow and was missing service packs. I downloaded a fresh copy of Crystal Reports XI R2 with all service packs up to SP6 and reinstalled it on my image. Printing doesn't break now.